# error in for loop, when using with vector size

Tags: c++

This is the sample code that i have written.
I am getting out put as follows,

```
size 0
Here
```

Why this code enters in to for loop even though value of myVec.size is zero

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  vector<int> myVec;
  cout <<" size  " << myVec.size() << endl;
  for (int i=0; i<myVec.size() -1; i++)
  {
   cout << " Here  " << endl;
   break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might like to start thinking about how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`size()` returns an unsigned type. With unsigned types, `0 - 1` "underflows" to the maximum value. Since `i` is less than the maximum possible value of the type it is converted to, the for loop is entered.

Answer (score 3):

Your question shows why it is usually better to avoid `unsigned` for numbers which "cannot be negative" and why it is unfortunate that standard library classes don't go with this guideline. See [Signed and Unsigned Types in Interfaces](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/C++ReportColumns/sep95.pdf) by Scott Meyers.

Since `myVec` is empty, its size is 0, and your `myVec.size() - 1` expression becomes 0 - 1, which would be -1 if the type was signed. However, it is unsigned, so it becomes a huge positive number instead.

In C++98/03, a better way to to iterate through a vector is to use iterators:

```
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = myVec.begin(); iter != myVec.end(); ++iter)
{
    int i = *iter;
}
```

In C++11, this can be written more concisely:

```
for (auto iter = myVec.begin(); iter != myVec.end(); ++iter)
{
    int i = *iter;
}
```

Or even better, use a range-based `for` loop:

```
for (auto i : myVec)
{
}
```

Comment: It only works in C++11. Chances are your compiler is simply too old.